# Buttons in Container Repeats itself - ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs5

I'm using two buttons inside an container in ExtJS and container I'm showing on radio buttons checked. But on pressing Cancel button again when I open the form, buttons get repeats itself. Here is the xds:

```
{
    "id": "MyContainer39",
    "cid": "container",
    "jsClass": "MyContainer39",
    "snapToGrid": 10,
    "userConfig": {
        "flex": "-ext-undefined-",
        "autoRef": "SelectContainer",
        "id": "SelectContainer"
    },
    "cn": [{
        "id": "MyButton20",
        "cid": "button",
        "jsClass": "MyButton20",
        "snapToGrid": 10,
        "userConfig": {
            "text": "MCW.lr.s_btn_selectAll",
            "style": "float:left; display:inline-block; margin-left:10px;",
            "flex": "-ext-undefined-",
            "autoRef": "SelectAll"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "MyButton21",
        "cid": "button",
        "jsClass": "MyButton21",
        "snapToGrid": 10,
        "userConfig": {
            "text": "MCW.lr.s_btn_deselectAll",
            "iconAlign": "right",
            "style": "float:left; display:inline-block; margin-left:15px;",
            "flex": "-ext-undefined-",
            "autoRef": "DeSelectAll"
        }
    }]
}
```

Radio Button checked condition:

```
if (card.internalServerDowloadLocation.checked == true) {
    Ext.getCmp('SelectContainer').show();
} else {
    Ext.getCmp('SelectContainer').hide();
}
```

Is there any way, so on cancel I can remove buttons from container and on load again add it to containers.

Comment: What is form here ? Cancel button I am assuming is part of container right. and what is meaning of "buttons get repeats itself". Please clear the question

Comment: @UDID Next time I open the screen, it's showing 4 buttons inside container instead of original two one.

Comment: Any code you written for handler of cancel button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it myself. Main issue was that in container both autoref and id's were same:

```
"userConfig": {
        "flex": "-ext-undefined-",
        "autoRef": "SelectContainer",
        "id": "SelectContainer"
    }
```

So I removed the autoref and its' working fine now.